# Pagination not working in custom page, only working in post page

Tags: pagination

```
global $wp_query;
$result = $wp_query;
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$original_query = $wp_query;
$wp_query = null;
$args=array(
    'post_type'=> 'post',
    'orderby'    => 'ID',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'order'    => 'DESC',         
    'posts_per_page'=>get_option( 'posts_per_page' ),
    'paged'=>$paged
);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$result = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $result-> have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $result->have_posts() ) : $result->the_post(); 
          get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );
     endwhile; 
     echo "<div class='pagenum_link'>";
         $total_pages = $result->max_num_pages;
         if ($total_pages > 1){
             $current_page = max(1, get_query_var('paged'));
             echo paginate_links(array(
                 'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
                 'format' => '/page/%#%',
                 'current' => $current_page,
                 'total' => $total_pages,
                 'prev_text'    => __('«'),
                 'next_text'    => __('»'),
             ));
         }
     echo "</div>";
else :
     get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', 'none' );
endif; 
wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: My answer was downvoted. Did you actually try it? If it didn't work, let me know and I can try and help further.

Comment: yes i try this code its not working

Answer (score -1):

Remove the following line from your `$args` array:

```
'post_type'=> 'post',
```

Or change it to:

```
'post_type'=> 'any',
```

This is only running the query on posts and will not work on pages.
The following explains this in more detail: https://wordpress.org/support/article/post-types/